# Looking to replace the year in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, t-sql, date

I am converting a date using `CONVERT(varchar,DateOfBirth,101)` for birthdates.

I want to show these dates with the current year, I've tried `REPLACE` but you can't use wildcards with it and when I use `DATEPART`, it doesn't format with the right digits for month and day.  I also can't add years because they are wildly different birthdates. Thanks.

Comment: Could you share any sample data?

Comment: Can you give an example of input and ouput? I.E. what is an example of one date that is input and the desired output?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to display the date as a string in `101` format for current year, one option uses a direct `format()`:

```
format(DateOfBirth, 'MM/dd/2020')
```

You can compute the current date dynamically:

```
format(DateOfBirth, concat('MM/dd/', year(getdate())))
```

On the other hand, if you want your result as a `date`, then you could use `datefromparts()`:

```
datefromparts(year(getdate()), month(DateOfBirth), day(DateOfBirth))
```

Comment: Nice!  One edge case when doing this is leap years - consider what happens when the birthday is '2000-02-29' - that will work in 2020, but not next year in 2021 ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This could helped you:

The code `CONVERT(varchar(5),GETDATE(),1)` return this `05/27` and then just add the year of the date

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(5),GETDATE(),1) + '/' + cast(year(getdate()) as varchar)
```

Or

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(5),GETDATE(),1) + '/' + convert(varchar,year(getdate()))
```

The result of both:

```
05/27/2020 --(This is my current date n.n )
```

This work but if you use a string something like your example DateOfBirth will be the variable and if this is a string (DateOfBirth = '5/27/1987') you need to convert the string DateOfBirth to Date:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(5),convert(date,DateOfBirth),1) + '/' + cast(year(GETDATE()) as varchar)
```

Or

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(5),convert(date,DateOfBirth),1) + '/' + convert(varchar,year(GETDATE()))
```

The Result of Both :

```
05/27/2020
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is a datevalue, you can use FORMAT function. If it is a character value, you can use RIGHT and REPLACE.

```sql
DECLARE @dateValue DATETIME = '05/12/1999'
DECLARE @dateCharValue VARCHAR(12) = '05/12/1999'

SELECT FORMAT(@dateValue, 'MM/dd/2020')
SELECT REPLACE(@dateCharValue, RIGHT(@dateCharValue,4),2020)
```

```sql
--Result
05/12/2020
```